# IE 6~8 ignoring font, background, and margins on sidebar

Tags: css, sidebar, browser-compatibility

I am using the default Twenty Twelve Wordpress theme with my site, and I am trying to customize the sidebar. The CSS I am using is:

```
.widget-area, #secondary{
float: right;
width: 210px;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;           
border-top: 1px solid #cacaca;
background-color: #efefef;
margin-top: 45px; }
```

The code for the sidebar is unchanged from the default template, and I am using text widget for the content of the sidebar. The problem page is here:

http://www.discusscps.com/gccenter/about-our-organization/

Chrome, Safari, and IE 9 have no problems, but in IE 6~8, font-family, borders, background colors, and the top margin is ignored.

I have tried everything I can think of here - any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is probably the wrong place to ask this kind of quetion as it is most likely something in your css or HTML which cause the problem and not wordpress itself. I suggest you to first fix the html validation errors you have on that page and if you still have this problem, ask in one of the other stacks.

Comment: This is definitely a CSS/html question, not one that requires WordPress knowledge, try asking on Stack Overflow

Comment: @MarkKaplun and Tom: Thank you for your answers. It was my first question on stackexchange, and in the future I will try to select a more appropriate forum. However, Vinod below provided advice that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added this CSS in below css3 media query and this css3 media rule does not support IE8 and below browsers so it is not applying css contained in its block.

```
/* Minimum width of 600 pixels. */
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) { 
.widget-area, #secondary{
float: right;
width: 210px;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;           
border-top: 1px solid #cacaca;
background-color: #efefef;
margin-top: 45px; }
}
```

To make it work just declare this css rule outside this media query block as following .

```
/* Minimum width of 600 pixels. */
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) { 

}
.widget-area, #secondary{
float: right;
width: 210px;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;           
border-top: 1px solid #cacaca;
background-color: #efefef;
margin-top: 45px; }
```

Comment: This worked immediately. Thank you so much - I don't think that I would have figured this out alone, and am grateful. --I do not have enough reputation to vote your answer up, but it really saved me.

Answer (score -1):

are you using reset.css ? 
if not you can download here
http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/

you can also use IE Conditional Comments

```
<!--[if IE 8]> = IE8
<!--[if lt IE 8]> = IE7 or below
<!--[if gte IE 8]> = greater than or equal to IE8
```

**Usages**

`<!--[if IE 8]>`

`<style type="text/css">`
    `/* css for IE 8 */`
`</style>`

`<![endif]-->`

`<!--[if lt IE 8]>`

`<link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

`<![endif]-->`

For more IE hacking take a visit here
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using a reset in the main stylesheet, but not a dedicated reset.css. The answer is good, but my problem is that I can't find any css that affects the sidebar for IE 6~8, so using a dedicated style sheet might not help me here.